# The UIScrollview always bounces back to top in IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview which always bounces to top after I scroll to bottom. I have tried numerous ways to fix this. I know there has been asked same kind of question but none of that helped me.
These are the code I have used

```
[self.nfaSscrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,3185)];
```

also

```
[self.NFASscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.NFASscrollview.frame.size.width,3185)];
```

This I have written in **viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.NFASscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.NFASscrollview.frame.size.width,3185)];
    _NFASscrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;

    _View3.hidden=YES;

    self.view1HeightConstraint.constant = 0.0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

3185  is just the (height+origin of Y) of the last content inside my Scroll view.

[image: This is the screenshot of my Layout]

[image: This is the screenshot of my Layout]

Screenshot of constraints of view

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think there might some problem with my constraints. I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: Variable names begin with lowercase letters. Doing otherwise is just confusing.

Comment: What is `NFAScrollviewCGSizeMake`?

Comment: @Fogmeister K I'll remember that.

Comment: @Fogmeister NFAScrollviewCGSizeMake returns the size of the scroll view.

Comment: can you show the code in that function.

Comment: Also, you are using auto layout. You shouldn’t need to set the content height manually. It will be calculated automatically. Have you set constraints on all the views inside the scroll view?

Comment: Yes I have set constraints on all the views inside the scroll view.

Comment: if you have used constraints then you cannot set content size  like  you are setting.

Comment: You are loading frames on ViewDidLoad. Sometimes on ViewDidLoad you don't have yet the correct frame that you need, so you should try on ViewWillAppear.

Comment: Where are you calling `setContentOffset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for **negative value** in **constraints** of your **super view** and **scrollview** and set it as **0**. Even I faced the same issue I fixed it by setting the **bottom space to** constraint of my **Super View** to **0**.

Answer (score 0):

Before you get the frame of **NFASscrollview**, try using `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]`. Because this allows you to get the current accurate frame of **NFASscrollview** from the constraints of Autolayout.

Comment: Actually, I'm not the final answer here, but just a correction of the constraints of Autolayout setting frame.